# IOS Vision framework running on simulator vs actual device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, vision

I use IOS Vision framework's VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest to detect a face in an image. I get the CGRect of the face using boundingbox property of VNFaceObservation. For some reason the cgrect is not identical for a same image when run on same iPad model with different IOS and also same IOS with different iPad models? The results (x,y,w,h) from different device/ios combination were off approximately by 1%. When I process the same image from the xcode simulator, all the combinations of different hardware and IOS model give the same results. Has anyone encountered this or know why there is this discrepancy?

Comment: This may be similar to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080366/ios-devices-handling-images-differently